# Orthogonal complements of subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I wanted to show that $U\subset W \implies W^\perp \subset U^\perp$. I have managed to show the implication that $U\subset W \implies W^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$ and I'm not quite sure how to make the subset strict?

Comment: If these are finite dimensional you could make an argument using dimension counting. That said, I suspect your existing argument could be made stronger to work instead.

Comment: These are finite dimensional, and my argument was very simple, I just took an element of $W^\perp$ and showed that it was also an element of $U^\perp$ but this only proves the non-strict case correct?

Comment: @Drevvvy Take into account that in advanced mathematics it is very often understood that $\;\subset\;$ is a *weak* inclusion...

Comment: so does that mean that $\subset$ often means the same thing as $\subseteq$

Comment: In finite dimensions it is surely true, but in infinite dimensions all sorts of unexpected things may happen.

Comment: Different people use different conventions. For some people $\subset$ means weak inclusion, and if they need to refer to strict inclusion (which is rarer), they use $\subsetneq$. Other people mirror order notation: $\subseteq$ means weak inclusion, and $\subset$ means strict inclusion. So without specifying which convention we are in, the symbol $\subset$ is ambiguous. But it is clear that Drevvvy is using the latter notational convention, so everything is fine.

Comment: @Drevvvy but no, we have to stick to one convention or the other. Never mix conventions. So within a single context, $\subset$ should never mean the same thing as $\subseteq.$

Comment: @ziggurism I'm not sure I follow this last comment. As far as I know, the symbol $\ \subseteq\ $ unambiguously means weak inclusion, and $\ \subsetneq\ $ unambiguously means strict inclusion. So if you're using $\ \subset\ $ to mean weak inclusion then it would be synonymous with $\ \subseteq\ $. Of course, if you use both symbols together, without making it clear that you're using them as synonyms, then you could well mislead your readers into mistaking your intended meaning of $\ \subset\ $.  If you merely meant that such usage should be avoided for that reason, then I agree with you.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera it's been a minute but yes I think we're saying the same thing. Your vocabulary for weak inclusion, strict inclusion should either be $\subseteq,\subsetneq$ or else $\subseteq, \subset$. You should never have all three symbols, but if for some reason you do you should make clear which two are synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

As Tony points out in his answer, the claim is not true if $U$ is not a linear subspace, since the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ *is* orthogonal to the linear closure of $U$.

Similarly, if $U$ is a linear subspace of a topological vector space, but is not a closed set, then we may have for example $U\subsetneq \bar U$, but then $U^\perp = \bar U^\perp.$

For example, in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}),$ let $U=c_0$ be the sequences which are eventually zero. Then $U\subsetneq \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, but $U^\perp= \ell^2(\mathbb{N})^\perp = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

The claim, as written, is not true. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $W = \mbox{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ and $U=W\backslash\{(0,1,0)\}$, i.e. $U$ is a the plane $W$ without one point. Then, $U\subset W$ but $W^\perp=U^\perp = \mbox{span}\{(0,0,1)\}$.

Consider instead a vector space $\mathcal{X}$ with $U\subset W\subset \mathcal{X}$ and $U$ and $W$ are linear subspaces. It is straightforward to show that $W^\perp\subseteq U^\perp$. Then, we can write $\mathcal{X} = U\oplus U^\perp$. **If we can show that** $w\in W\cap U^\perp$ exists, we are done, since then $w\in U^\perp$ because $\mathcal{X}=U\cup U^\perp$ but also $w\not\in W^\perp$ since $w\in W$ so in fact we have $W^\perp\subset U^\perp$.

Comment: I suspect $U$ and $W$ were meant to be subspaces of some larger vector space $V$.

Comment: That's why I said "The claim, as written"

Comment: In the last paragraph, $\mathcal X=U\cup U^\bot$ isn't correct. $U\cup U^\bot$ spans $\mathcal X$ but it isn't equal to $\mathcal X$. You probably meant + rather than $\cup$. But then a little more work is needed to finish the proof, because not just any $w\in W\setminus U$ will do what you need.

Comment: You're right, it should have been a sum instead of a union and this requires more delicacy. Thanks for catching this.